# fetch records based on time from mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

There are attribute of time and and date in order schema mongodb . I want to  fetch order details from mongo db which delivery time and date is near what could be the possible query and currently i am storing the time and date as String data type.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide code samples of what you currently have? It would help better understand what you want to achieve.